# How to create first Windows Forms DevExpress application

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am new to using DevExpress.the process of creating a WinForm using DevExpress isn't clear to me Yet. I tried reading the DevExpress documentation but it seems more difficult than using WinForms just confused me more.
I found myself using only WinForms to create my User interfaces without using DEVExpress.

So please can you please help me and make it more clear to me how can I create a first WinForms devexpress app?

Comment: Ask Devexpress support.

Comment: maybe [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114441/Build-an-Application) is a good read for you. Also do not be afraid to ask lots of questions at the support page from devexpress, they have always helped me with any questions even when it sometimes was not devexpress related

Comment: Thank you @GuidoG !! I will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After DevExpress components have been installed, you can create a new WinForms project as usual and then drop required controls from the VS toolbox to the target Form or UserControl.

DevEpress also provides [Template Gallery](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/16492/What-s-Installed/Template-Gallery) that can be used to build your project skeleton.

Once a new project is created, you can use the [Project Settings Page](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/120180/What-s-Installed/Project-Settings-Page) to manage your project appearance settings - apply a specific skin, font, etc. Don't also forget to convert your Forms and UserControls to their skinnable DevExpress counterparts. Refer to [Forms and User Controls](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114561/Controls-and-Libraries/Forms-and-User-Controls) where all skinnable Forms and UserControls DevExpress counterparts are listed.

If you have additional questions, please feel free to contact the DevExpress support team using [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create).